# Biber and german umlauts

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a problem with biber (2.1) and german umlauts. My bibliography Thesis.bib has only one entry:

```
   @article{cite1,
   author = {G{\"{o}}, A.},
   journal = {journal},
   title = {{lalelu}},
   }
```

And my main.tex file is:

```
    \documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Thesis.bib}
    \begin{document}
    \cite{cite1}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

I compile via pdflatex main && biber main. The output of biber is

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Thesis.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
```

with exit code 1. 
When I remove the umlaut from the author line in Thesis.bib everything is fine. 
It doesn't make a difference if the umlaut is an another field of the bib entry and I have the same problem with \% and \&.

I'm using OSX 10.11 with texlive2015 from MacPorts.

Has somebody encountered a similar problem?

Best wishes,
Peter

Comment: If you are not happy with daleif's answer, which is the way to go, would it be possible to show the entire `.blg` file? Can you also make sure that the MWE actually produces the problem. When I copied your code, it worked fine on my machine (both files encoded in UTF8)

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing MacTeX2015 from `http://tug.org/mactex/`?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to your document, `biber` runs and outputs in UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Soo.... finally I fixed it!
It turned out that there was a problem with the texlive installation. After the upgrade to OSX 10.11 I didn't update the MacPorts installation.

Furthermore I had a problem with the .bib files that are generated by Mendeley. In case the bib entry has a field month, Mendeley exports an abbreviation like March=mar, which causes a problem to biber. biber unfortunately exits without proper error message. That problem is mentioned in the biber manual.

Comment: Could explain this more detaild? I get the same error, but my Mendeley bib-file contains fields like:month = {jan}

Comment: Try month={January} (or remove the field at all)